# $x^2 + 3x + a \equiv 0 \mod n$ has an even number of solutions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n \ge 2$ be even, and $a$ be any integer.  I would like to show that
$$x^2 + 3x + a \equiv 0 \mod n$$ has an even number of solutions.

I'm not sure how to begin.  I was thinking induction, but got nowhere.

Answer (score 7):

If $q$ is a solution, show that $n-q-3$ is a different solution.

Comment: How did you get to this magic number ?

Comment: Wouldn't this imply that the equation has an infinite number of solutions?

Comment: Well no matter what you have an infinite number of solutions since $x$ and $x+n$ are the same modulo $n.$ You probably want a (finite) even number of equivalence classes of solution, and Gerry Myerson gives you this (you have to note that $q$ and $n-q-3$ are of different parity though).

Comment: Can you explain how this shows that there are an even number of equivalence classes of solutions?

Comment: @Belgi, he used the fact that the sum of the roots is $-3 \bmod n$.

Comment: $q$ and $-q-3$ are in different equivalence classes, because $2q$ is even but $3$ is odd.

Comment: @lhf Why do the roots sum to -3? That seems false unless $n$ is prime; take e.g. $a=0, n=10$.

Comment: @user7530, the roots don't all sum to $-3$, but if $q$ is a root, so is $-3-q$.

Comment: @user7530, you're right of course. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @user63060, it shows that solutions come in pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would solve it.

First, by the Chinese remainder theorem, it suffices to show that $f(x) = x^2+3x+a$ has an even number of solutions mod $2^m$. In fact this equation has either 0 or 2 solutions, which I will prove by induction.

For $m=1$, clearly $f(x)\equiv 0$ has either 0 or 2 solutions, depending on the parity of $a$.

Now suppose $r$ is a solution of $f(x)\equiv 0 \pmod {2^{m-1}}$. Then there is one and only one solution $s$ with $f(s) \equiv 0 \pmod {2^m}$ and $s\equiv r \pmod {2^{m-1}}$. Indeed, 
$$(r+2^{m-1}k)^2+3(r+2^{m-1}k)+a\equiv (r^2 + 3r + a) + 2^{m-1}k \equiv 0 \pmod{2^m}$$
holds for exactly one of $k=0,1$ depending on the parity of $(r^2+3r+a)/2^{m-1}.$

Comment: Presumably, the $n$ in $\mod2^n$ isn't the $n$ in the statement of the question.

Comment: Right; I've relabeled, thanks.